# I'm not entirely sure if that topology is "proper"

Tags: topology

I have a strange case on my model and I'm not entirely sure If it's in a "proper" way of doing things.
The plane number 1 shows pretty much what I've stummbled upon. As much as those look like two tris they are basically quads. Strange quads nonetheless. They also subdivide into the kinda ok but kinda mess that can be seen on plane number 2/ After some clean up though those quads look nice.

The question is if it's ok to leave that one vertex floating in the middle or would it be better to stick to version number 3. [image: Image of a plane]

Comment: Hello, it really depends on what you're trying to achieve, if your object is completely flat, the central vertex is useless, and anyway if this vertex is here to pull the shape in some ways, it's probably not the best practice. You don't always need quads when tris or ngons are ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're showing is a "degenerate quad", where three vertices are collinear.  Such a quad may as well be a triangle-- the extra vertex exists solely to meet some "all quad" design goal, but in this case, you'd be better off with triangles.

Topology depends on application.  Whenever you wonder whether something is good topology, all you have to do is ask, does it do what I want it to do?  In other words, if it is a rendering mesh, is the render what I want it to be?  However, for most situations where somebody is asking if this is good topo-- those situations being smooth shaded rendering meshes-- no, this is not good topo.  There are a number of reasons for that, but the simplest to explain is that it may create discontinuous normals on your mesh.

Remember, prior to rendering, all quads are tessellated into triangles.  There are two ways to triangulate any given quad, and it's typical to leave the precise triangulation up to the engine, up to Blender.  Let's look at what happens to vertex color as a quad approaches degeneracy:

[image]

The vertex color is not interpolated over the entire quad; it is interpolated over two triangles.  As the quad approaches degeneracy, one of these triangles approaches zero area.  As it does so, the influence of the red vertex over the face approaches zero.

The same thing can happen with normals, which are interpolated across triangles similarly.  The influence of the single custom normal here is also approaching zero:

[image]

Blender appears to have some weird things it does to address this, flipping triangulation to prevent literally zero-area faces-- I haven't noticed this before, but it strikes me as unwise, because you don't want animation to cause your triangulation to flip.  Most other engines will not change triangulation to prevent zero area faces.

For animation, in Blender, this topology is even worse.  To demonstrate, and as a demonstration of why Blender's triangulation flipping is unwise, and why other rendering engines don't do it:

[image]

That's a UV mapped wave texture.  UV is yet another vertex property that is interpolated across triangulated faces, same as vertex color or smooth-shaded normals.  Notice the popping as the triangulation changes.

As I mentioned, there are plenty of other reasons to avoid degenerate quads; as an example, I have seen autoweight failures on meshes with degenerate quads that resolved on dissolving the degenerate vertex.  Most mesh tools are not based around the existence of degenerate (or concave) quads.

For typical rendering topology, a lot of times beginners get hung up on "all quads", because that's the easiest part of topology to understand, and it provides a reasonable goal before they understand *why* topology is important.  But topology is about balancing multiple issues: quads are important, but so are the angles of those quads, and so is the aspect of those quads, and so are the poles, and so is how planar those quads are; I think there's a good case that vertex count is another issue that should be considered as a topology property.  Sometimes, those factors are a balancing act.  All-quad at any cost, at the expense of other characteristics of good topology, is a fool's bargain.

Generally, a quad-only topology is recommended as **part** of good topology for improving smoothness from Catmull-Clark subdivided meshes.  (It's important for normals even without CC subdiv, but that's not as big a deal.)  But a degenerate quad like this isn't going to improve CC subdivision (as mentioned by Jachym Michal, it will create pinching), and it will create problems elsewhere, even in the absence of CC subdivision.  If you cannot dissolve the edge to create a quad spanning the mirror line, you are almost certainly better off with triangles.  If you're happy with your render, and you think you need that vertex for some reason, go for it.  The only important measures of a mesh's quality are the renders that it produces. But if you ever run into problems with your render in that region, you know where to look first.

Comment: Thanks! That pretty much describes everything I wanted to hear :D. Normally I'm not to hang up on the "quads are better" mindset. As you said topology should be as good as it needs to be. Most of my models go into external programs so either way they end up in triangles. Still I'm not that familiar with subdivision modeling and I'm trying to get it to at least a decent level. Thanks for both of your and Michal replies they helped a lot :D

Answer (score 3):

The middle vertex serves to change the edge flow.
Which might be desirable under some circumstances.

With *Subdivision Surface* it strengthens the geometry and may introduce pinching.

[image]